# C# Cognex ,why he say null reference exception

Tags: c#, vision

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmuoh.jpg)

code:

```
CogFindCircleLastRunRecordConstants.BestFitCircle;
        CogFindCircleTool_.Run();

        if ((CogFindCircleTool_.Results.GetCircle() != null) && (CogFindCircleTool_.Results.GetCircle().Visible == true))
        {
            cogRecordDisplay1.Record = CogFindCircleTool_.CreateLastRunRecord().SubRecords["InputImage"];
```

Comment: because the results haven't been set... why you may ask? i doubt any can really know except the person who wrote this

Answer (score 0):

This error is because `.Results` is `null`, yet you're trying to call the `GetCircle()` method on it.

One way to handle this is to use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (`?.`), which returns `null` if the left hand side is null, otherwise continues with the method or property on the right hand side:

```
// If Results is null, the call to GetCircle will not happen, and the result will be null
// Not needed on the second condition, since '&&' would return 'false' right away
if ((CogFindCircleTool_.Results?.GetCircle() != null) &&  
    (CogFindCircleTool_.Results.GetCircle().Visible == true))
```

You could shorten your code even further by adding another `.?` when accessing the `Visible` property, and then we don't need to explicitly check for `.GetCircle() != null` first.

Below, if `Results` is `null` or `GetCircle` returns `null`, the expression will fail (because `null != true`), otherwise the condition `Visible == true` will be evaluated:

```
if (CogFindCircleTool_.Results?.GetCircle()?.Visible == true)
```

---

In the comments you stated that you have a line like this inside the `if` statement:

```
Label.SetXYText(CogFindCircleTool_.Results.GetCircle().CenterX, 
    CogFindCircleTool_.Results.GetCircle().CenterY, "(" + 
    Math.Round(CogFindCircleTool_.Results.GetCircle().CenterX, 3).ToString() + 
    "," + Math.Round(CogFindCircleTool_.Results.GetCircle().CenterY, 3).ToString() + ")");
```

One thing to improve performance is to capture the result fo the `GetCircle()` method once rather than calling it over and over again, which takes extra processing cycles. This will also make the code shorter and more readable. You can also use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) instead of concatenation to shorten the code a little more.

You also mentioned that you were still getting a null reference exception on the inner line, which could only mean that `Label` is null (from what I can tell). If so, we could use the `?.` operator when calling the `SetXYText` method:

```
// Capture the result of GetCircle() once
var circle = CogFindCircleTool_?.Results?.GetCircle();

if (circle?.Visible == true)
{
    Label?.SetXYText(circle.CenterX, circle.CenterY, 
        $"({Math.Round(circle.CenterX, 3)},{Math.Round(circle.CenterY, 3)})");
}
```

Note that the code above will not do anything if something is null. If you want to do something else if `circle` is `null` or `Label` is `null`, then you should explicitly check that rather than use the `?.` operator:

```
if (circle == null) 
{ 
    // do something if circle is null 
} 
else if (circle.Visible == true) 
{ 
    if (Label == null) 
    { 
        // do something if Label is null 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Label.SetXYText(circle.CenterX, circle.CenterY, 
            $"({Math.Round(circle.CenterX, 3)},{Math.Round(circle.CenterY, 3)})");
    } 
}
```

Comment: But i have run successfully before.

Comment: i just try to run what you said ,but the next line Label.SetXYText(CogFindCircleTool_.Results.GetCircle().CenterX, CogFindCircleTool_.Results.GetCircle().CenterY, "(" + Math.Round(CogFindCircleTool_.Results.GetCircle().CenterX, 3).ToString() + "," + Math.Round(CogFindCircleTool_.Results.GetCircle().CenterY, 3).ToString() + ")"); he still say null

Comment: I don’t understand now is  when CogFindCircleTool_.run(),he should record the value.

Comment: First of all you should capture the value of `GetCircle` once rather than calling the method over and over. Also don't try to do so much in one line. Break it up so you can see where it falls

Comment: I updated the answer with a code sample that might help.